# What's the difference between the "/FAs command line option" (generate asm output) or the "Goto Disassembly" menu option?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, disassembly

What's the difference the "/FAs command line option" (to generate asm output) and the "Goto Disassembly" menu option?

I know Visual Studio has two methods to view assembly code.

Method 1: MSVC Add /FAs to the command line options to generate a .asm file.

Method 2: Goto Disassembly menu option

Q1. What is the difference between the assembly code generated by Method 1 and Method 2?

Q2. Method 1 and Method 2, which way to view assembly code is better?

Q3. What is the default disassembler for VS in method 2?

Answer (score 4):

"Go To Disassembly" is a feature of the Visual Studio IDE Debugging experience while the command line options for outputting disassembly are a feature of the C++ compiler. These are completely different things, they have nothing to do with each other and work in completely opposite ways. First of all, "Go To Disassembly" does not do any assembling. It does the exact opposite: it interprets a piece of memory of a running process as machine code and shows you what the assembly code for that machine code would look like. An assembler turns assembly code into machine code. A disassembler turns machine code into assembly code. What's happening here is the latter. That's why it's called "Go To *Dis*assembly". I don't think the disassembler the VS debugger uses is accessible as a separate tool. At least I'm not aware of any documentation that would mention such a tool and I'd never have seen an option to change which disassembler the debugger should use. So your question about the default disassembler the debugger uses is kinda mute, it simply uses the one that's built into the debugger…

When you use the compiler options to output assembly code, the compiler writes the assembly code it generates for your source code to a file. This allows you to look at the assembly code the compiler turned your source code into. Contrary to the "Go To Disassembly" feature of the debugger, which will show you the assembly code for the actual machine code that is actually running in a given process at any given moment, the assembly output by the compiler is the entire assembly the compiler produced for a single source file. Note that this happens for each source file, before the actual program is linked. So the assembly you'll see there is not the assembly of the final program, it's just the assembly generated for the individual source file. If you're using whole program optimization, this assembly will not necessarily correspond to the machine code that actually ends up in the program.

Conclusion: There is no "better way" between these two options. Each of these does something completely different…

Comment: Thank you very much, can I use method 1 to debug the program?

Comment: @FredHu I'm not sure what you mean by "debug the program". Unless the bug you're looking for specifically has to do with what machine code the compiler generates for your source file, it will be a lot more pleasant to use the debugger to debug your program…the debugger let's you inspect the program as it is running…the assembly output by the compiler is just that, assembly output by the compiler…all you can do with that is stare at it…